# How to properly flip 2D character with new Unity4.3 2D framework? (Rotation of gameobjects during animation)

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, 2d, game-engine

i'm already checked official Unity 4.3 example project, and there they use

```
Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
theScale.x *= -1;
transform.localScale = theScale;
```

This works pretty well, but. But i'm encountered an trouble, not sure this trouble with this Flip or with something else.

I'm use Animator to animate my characters, i have `Attack` animation, which in addition to the sprite animation also move character's `Hand`, which can carry the `Weapon`. Problem is when i flip the character to opposite direction `Hand` will move wrong (not as planned), which is wrong. [(video below will be more descriptive)](http://youtu.be/qpMK2gRgDz8)

I discovered that this problem occure only if i modify the `Hand`'s `rotation` in animation, so if i works only with `.position` this works well, but i need the `rotation`!

What is best way to get this work?

**Here the youtube video:** http://youtu.be/qpMK2gRgDz8

*At video i show animation without rotation uses, hand moves correct. But next i show it with rotation, as you can see when character turned right this works well, but when left, its completely wrong.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do cannot be done with scaling cause scaling does not change the rotation of the object and so the forward vector remains the same. You must create double sided objects and just rorate them 180 degrees or you can ue a shader that draws a polygon even when its normal vector is against the camera.